# How can I use gnome-terminal in qt creator?

Tags: gnome-terminal, qt-creator

I can adjust the settings to use a terminal rather than just plain output. However, I can't seem to figure out the correct command to input for using gnome-terminal. I can use 'xterm -e', a fine enough solution, but I figured I'd like to know anyway.

When I try to use 'gnome-terminal -e', running my program will result in a blank terminal quickly opening and closing. I have to 'break' the execution afterward (sort of like an infinite loop). When using 'gnome-terminal -x' I get:

> Cannot connect creator comm socket /tmp/qt_temp.h17333/stub-socket: No
>   such file or directory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue is reported as a bug in Qt Creator.
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-1633

---

**Update:** Seems to be **[fixed](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-1633?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel#changehistorydetails_607798)** on 31 Aug 2012.

Comment: How does this answer the question? I have QtCreator built on Mar 14 2016 and it still shows a blank `gnome-terminal`. The "fixed" link is broken.

Comment: Here's a comment in [the bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-1633) from 2012: *In 2.4.1 the bug is still here. I tried gnome-terminal -e but it has no effect at all; gnome-terminal -x opens the terminal but outputs nothing into it. I am running Ubuntu. This bug has been hanging since 2010?!*  I guess we're up to six years and still not fixed. Bug is closed though? Don't hold your breath, bug is closed as "Resolved", whatever that means.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent of `xterm -e` for `gnome-terminal` is `gnome-terminal -e`, try it. If `-e` does not work try `-x`.

Comment: Hi, brunopereira81, lgarzo. I'm sorry, guys, I wrote the question in a rush and completely forgot to add that I've tried these two. Please read my updated description.

Comment: It worked !!! but  why -e is not working ??

Answer (score 1):

You can figure out all available options with `gnome-terminal --help-all`:

```
-e, --command      Execute the argument to this option inside the terminal
```

Comment: Hi, brunopereira81, lgarzo. I'm sorry, guys, I wrote the question in a rush and completely forgot to add that I've tried these two. Please read my updated description.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue and it turned out I had too many instances of my console application running in the background. I left my settings to `gnome-terminal -x` and instead just closed all the running instances of my application then tried again and it worked.